# How to identify measure words in Chinese text?

Tags: natural-language-processing

[*Measure words*](https://digchinese.com/measure-words) (aka *classifiers*) are used in Chinese to "measure" things, e.g.

> 三**杯**牛奶
> Three **glasses** of milk
>
> 那**个**人
> That person
>
> 一**只**乌鸦
> One crow
>
> 一**公斤**豆腐
> A **kilo** of tofu

We don't have an equivalent in English [they're not collective nouns (e.g. a murder of crows)].  It'd help reading Chinese text to be able to highlight measure words in a distinct color.

Thus, I'm interested in the following problem:

***Input***: Chinese plaintext.
***Output***: Identification of which characters are measure words in that plaintext.

It's a highly restricted version of Chinese text segmentation, and I expect it would be substantially simpler, e.g. there's only a short list of characters which can be measure words.  It may even be considered "solved".

However, there's some nuances which make this challenging, e.g., repeated measure words e.g. 个个 and 一根根, and characters in measure words can also belong to Chinese words, e.g. 个人, 家庭.  Nevertheless, there may only be a small number of exceptions here.

**Question**: How to identify measure words in Chinese text?

Searching for [`Chinese measure words`](https://dl.acm.org/action/doSearch?AllField=Chinese%20measure%20words) in ACM didn't give anything relevant, but this problem may have arisen as a sideline in other work on Chinese text segmentation.